# I have two list with some values I have to compare all values and I want to iterate unmatched values form both the list in python programing

Tags: python, list

I want to compare two lists and extract unmatched values.

Example:

```
list1 = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1']

list2 = ['A1', 'B1', 'D1', 'E1']
```

so the 'C1' is not in list 2 so I want output as

```
output: C1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) for [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s:

```
set(list1) ^ set(list2)
# {'C1'}
```

depending on what you really need, you may need the [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)

```
set(list1) - set(list2)
# {'C1'}
```

Comment: This assumes there aren't any duplicate entries in either list

Comment: @Sayse agreed. the question is not really clear in several respects (are the lists treated the same or not?)...